# Question about "convention"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Although I know the word "convention" means "agreement to behave in a particular way", I cannot still simplify the line below.

> "Malaysia needs to take control under the Chicago convention of those investigations."

Here is the full context:

> Australia's Deputy Prime Minister Warren Truss said the Malaysian statement moved the search to a new phase.
>
> "It moves it to a stage where we are now investigating an accident, a loss of an aircraft and some new decisions will have to be taken now about the direction of future operations," Truss told reporters.
>
> "Malaysia needs to take control under the Chicago **convention** of those investigations."
>
> The United States said it was sending an undersea Navy drone to Australia, in addition to a high-tech black box detector, to help in the search.

Comment: See also: Wiki article on [Chicago Convention on International Civil Aviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Convention_on_International_Civil_Aviation)

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to be confused with the sentence because it's a quote and it had to be reported as is.

Let me simplify.

Remove some stuff to get the main idea:

> Malaysia needs to take control of those investigations.

Also, "**The Chicago convention**" is a *proper noun* and should have been written as "**The Chicago Convention**". [It's a law about airplanes and air travel.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Convention_on_International_Civil_Aviation)

So put it back together:

> Malaysia needs to take control of those investigations under the Chicago Convention.

Comment: Yes; lexically, the *Chicago Convention* is akin to the *Geneva Convention*.

Answer (score 0):

If I rearrange the sentence it will come down to -

"...needs to take control of those investigation under Chicago convention"

I think "under Chicago convention" means here "in accordance with or following Chicago convention"

See the definition 5 of **[Under](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/under)**

**Under** - according to a particular law, agreement, or system

**Example** -

> 1. Under the terms of the agreement, our company will receive 40% of the profits.
> 2. The boy is considered a minor under British law.
> 3. All individuals have basic human rights, that are recognized under international law.